# Is there a way to add 4f-oribital information in Pseudopotential?

Tags: orbitals, pseudopotentials

Now, I'm calculating with a Quantum Espresso program

I want to need Eu pseudopotential file with 4f orbital information. But I couldn't find that file, no matter how much I search on the internet. Because of this, I haven't been able to calculate and I'm only seeing the error screen for several days.  I attatch the picture of error.[file1] [image]

**Is there anyone who can share the "Pseudopotential file of Eu atom" containing 4f-orbital information?**

Comment: Can you please include the error as a code block rather than an image? This makes it easier for users who use screen readers to read the content and can make it easier to copy/paste parts of the message to search specific terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the PP: Eu.pbe-spdfn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF. I have used this one for Hubbard correction of Eu-4f orbitals a while back. I have uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gF19GPEz3CkH9uTXN52Vw5ATJch1DJax/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello,  Thank you for replying. I confirmed your reply today. I try to connect your google site saved Eu-4f orbitals, but i couldn't connect. I need your approval. Could you please allow me access?

Comment: Done, try again

Comment: Thanks! I confirmed. it works well.!! Thanks to you,  finally, I was able to begin research.!! I have a additional question about this pseudopotential. Could you explain how to make 4f-orbital Pseudopotential? or Is there a library treats with 4f-ones?

Comment: You can create your own PP using various codes, I have not done it yet since for most cases there are already good and tested PP available. https://www.materialscloud.org/discover/sssp/table/efficiency has a good overview, there you can also find Eu.paw.z_17.atompaw.wentzcovitch.v1.2 (download SSSP_1.3.0_PBEsol_precision), which also has Eu-4f occupied, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.commatsci.2014.07.030 for details about creating those using ATOMPAW code.

Comment: Thank you. I got a lot of help from you. I will use this site often.